# Copy values from different sheets and paste it in a master file

Tags: vba, excel

Im want to create some VBA code to copy values from several sheet and paste it into one master file.

I have the following steps:

1. Go to a sheet and select a range

   ```
   Sheets("V01 DEN HAAG").Select
   Range("H7").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
   Selection.Copy
   ```
2. Go to the master file / select the lowest row, offset it by one and paste the values

   ```
   Sheets("DATASET").Select
   Range("B3").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   ActiveCell.Paste
   ```

There seems to be a small error though with the last "ActiveCell.Paste" statement. It gives me the error:

Object doesn't support this property or method.

Any thoughts what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveCell` is an object of class `Excel.Range` and this class doesn't have such a method as `Paste`.
You need to use `PasteSpecial` instead with parameter `Paste` set to `xlPasteAll`:

```
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

---

However, this is not a good practice to select ranges when copying/pasting them. Instead, you should use variables of `Range` type. Below is an example how to do the same task by using variables:

```
Sub x()
    Dim sourceRange As Excel.Range
    Dim destinationRange As Excel.Range
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Set the reference to [sourceRange].
    Set sourceRange = Sheets("V01 DEN HAAG").Range("H7", Range("H7").End(xlToRight))

    'Find the initial cell.
    Set destinationRange = Sheets("DATASET").Range("B3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

    'Resize [destinationRange] to the same size as [sourceRange].
    With sourceRange
        Set destinationRange = destinationRange.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
    End With


    'Actual copying & pasting.
    Call sourceRange.Copy
    Call destinationRange.PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)


End Sub
```